# Clean up improperly formatted phone numbers

Tags: strings, formatting, clojure

This is a problem from [Exercism here](https://exercism.org/tracks/clojure/exercises/phone-number), the goal is to clean up badly formatted phone numbers. The rules are:

- If the phone number is less than 10 digits assume that it is a bad number
- If the phone number is 10 digits assume that it is good
- If the phone number is 11 digits and the first number is 1, trim the 1 and use the first 10 digits
- If the phone number is 11 digits and the first number is not 1, then it is a bad number
- If the phone number is more than 11 digits assume that it is a bad number

A function should `pretty-print` the numbers in the form `(123) 456-7890`.

Here is my solution. I'm very new to Clojure and am sure it's not idiomatic in parts. For example, should I have stored the different parts of the number as separate variables?

I would also be interested in tips on how to format the code to make it easier to read, I'm only aware of [lispy-multiline](https://oremacs.com/lispy/#lispy-multiline) which I find a bit too aggressive.

All feedback much appreciated.

```
(ns phone-number)

(defn digit-not-one-or-zero [digit]
  (and (not (= \0 digit))
       (not (= \1 digit))))

(defn clean-number [num-string]
  ;; strip all non-digit characters from a string
  (filter #(Character/isDigit %) num-string))

(defn check-valid [num-string]
  ;; number is valid only if:
  ;; a) length is between 10-11 chars
  ;; b) if 11 chars, first digit must be 1
  ;; c) (after stripping first digit if 11), first and fourth can't be 0 or 1
  (let [clean-string (clean-number num-string)
        len (count clean-string)]
    (if (or (< len 10) (> len 11))
      false
      (if (= len 11)
        (if (= \1 (first clean-string))
          (check-valid (rest clean-string))
          false)
        (if (and (digit-not-one-or-zero (first clean-string))
                 (digit-not-one-or-zero (nth clean-string 3)))
          true
          false)))))

(defn number [num-string]
  (if (check-valid num-string)
    (let [clean-string (clean-number num-string)]
      (if (= (count clean-string) 10)
        (apply str (clean-number clean-string)) (apply str (rest (clean-number clean-string)))))
    "0000000000"))

(defn area-code [num-string]
  ;; get the first 3 chars of the cleaned up number
  (apply str (take 3 (number num-string))))

(defn pretty-print [num-string]
  (let [formatted-number (number num-string)]
    (apply str (concat
                "(" (area-code num-string) ")" " " (subs formatted-number 3 6) "-" (subs formatted-number 6)))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to look at [Clojure Cheatsheet](https://clojure.org/api/cheatsheet) and get familiar with the functions dedicated for working with strings. There is also the library `clojure.string`, containing a few more. With these functions, you won't have to convert your string into sequence and then back repeatedly.

Take for example your `pretty-print`- `subs` returns string, `concat` returns sequence, `apply str` returns string again. Pick the correct data structure at the beginning, use dedicated functions and convert as little as possible.

Use `:require` in `ns` to include `clojure.string` library:

```
(ns phone-number
  (:require [clojure.string :as s])
  (:gen-class))
```

I will start with the `area-code`. This function could be improved with [`->>`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) (thread-last macro) and [`clojure.string/join`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/join) like this:

```
(defn area-code [num-string]
  (->> (number num-string)
       (take 3)
       s/join))
```

But you can also use `subs`:

```
(defn area-code [num-string]
  (subs (number num-string) 0 3))
```

Next, `pretty-print`. You can use [`format`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/format) here:

```
(defn pretty-print [num-string]
  (let [validated (number num-string)]
    (format "(%s) %s-%s" (area-code validated)
            (subs validated 3 6)
            (subs validated 6))))
```

Next, `digit-not-one-or-zero`. You usually create a set with these elements and call it on your argument, something like:

```
(defn digit-not-one-or-zero [digit]
  (not (#{\0 \1} digit)))
```

Or even shorter:

```
(def digit-not-one-or-zero (complement #{\0 \1}))
```

Your `clean-number` is ok (I would just add `s/join` at the end to ensure it will return a string, as any other function here), unless you want to use some regex:

```
(defn clean-number [num-string]
  (s/replace num-string #"\D" ""))
```

Next, `number` and `check-valid`.

- Don't use nested `if`s- learn about [`cond`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cond), [`condp`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/condp) and [`case`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/case) and use these. [`When`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/when) can be also useful here.
- Don't use `(if ... true false)`. In Clojure, all values are logically true or false. The only "false" values are `false` and `nil` - all other values are logically true. So, take this example:

```
(if (and (digit-not-one-or-zero (first clean-string))
         (digit-not-one-or-zero (nth clean-string 3)))
  true
  false)
```

You can just write:

```
(and (digit-not-one-or-zero (first clean-string))
     (digit-not-one-or-zero (nth clean-string 3)))
```

- `check-valid` is too long- you should break it into smaller functions.

So, here is my version you can study. Note how using short functions, idioms and proper flow-control macros increased readability:

```
(ns phone-number
  (:require [clojure.string :as s])
  (:gen-class))

(def allowed-digits (complement #{\0 \1}))

(defn clean-number [num-string]
  (s/replace num-string #"\D" ""))
```

```
(defn validate10 [s]
  (and (allowed-digits (.charAt s 0))
       (allowed-digits (.charAt s 3))
       s))

(defn validate11 [s]
  (when (= \1 (.charAt s 0))
    (validate10 (subs s 1))))
```

```
(defn validate [num-string]
  (condp = (count num-string)
    11 (validate11 num-string)
    10 (validate10 num-string)
    false))

(defn number [num-string]
  (if-let [valid (validate (clean-number num-string))]
    valid
    "0000000000"))

(defn area-code [num-string]
  (subs (number num-string) 0 3))

(defn pretty-print [num-string]
  (let [validated (number num-string)]
    (format "(%s) %s-%s" (area-code validated)
            (subs validated 3 6)
            (subs validated 6))))
```

**EDIT:** Alternative solution with regexes:

```
(defn number [num-string]
  (if-let [valid (->> (s/replace num-string #"\D" "")
                      (re-matches #"1?([^01]..[^01].{6})")
                      second)]
    valid
    "0000000000"))

(defn area-code [num-string]
  (subs (number num-string) 0 3))

(defn pretty-print [num-string]
  (s/replace (number num-string)
             #"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})"
             "($1) $2-$3"))
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is all really helpful. Do you have any suggestions for rules for formatting?